In systemd-networkd, when trying to [Match] an ethernet interface in a .network file, what is the difference between `Name=en*` and `Type=ether`?
I haven't been capable of finding anything on the different performance implications of Name=en* and Type=ether.
The only difference I have found is that Type=ether also matches virtual ethernet ports, while Name=en* doesn't.

What is this regarding? Could you share some of the context this question exists within? What are you trying to do where this question came up?

Trying to [match] an interface in a .network file

Please add that and other clarifying information to the question itself, to improve it and clarify it.

there's ... 3-4 different network management setups in linux. Its really worth including which one specifically and a snippet of a config file

@JourneymanGeek is the systemd tag not sufficient?

systemd is comically broad - and while my distro uses systemd, I currently use the default netplan for network management, there's systemd.networkd, network manager, classic /etc/networks/interfaces...

@JourneymanGeek Noted. Furthermore, adding a snippet of the config file seems a bit redundant as the entire config file is this:
`[Match]
Type=ether
[Network]
DHCP=yes`

Systemd-networkd configuration is only applied once per interface (or once per 'networkctl reload') – it is neither per-packet nor per-connection, unlike e.g. iptables interface match – so any differences in performance are imperceptible unless you have literally thousands of interfaces to configure (and even then, I suspect networkd's general logic will still be the bottleneck and any difference in strcmp vs wildcard match will be a rounding error).
The only practical difference is that Name= can be arbitrary – en* will only match the naming style that systemd uses, but it will not match e.g. the standard kernel names (eth#) in case the user has disabled systemd naming, or any kind of custom name that the user might have defined (either via .link files or via udev rules, as was done in the past).
In short, there is no guarantee that an Ethernet interface is named en*, nor that every interface named en* is an Ethernet interface.

A noteworthy difference.
Do you also know of any different performance implications between the two?

Systemd-networkd configuration is only applied once per interface – not per-packet – so any differences in performance are imperceptible unless you have literally thousands of interfaces (and even then, I suspect networkd's general logic will still be the bottleneck and any difference in strcmp vs wildcard match will be a rounding error).

Type=ether is a strcmp? I was expecting it to use some form of numerical "type ID"

I seem to remember it checking against the type reported via /sys/class/net, not against a Netlink field... and that Type=ether is actually fiction because it checks for absence of reported type (as Ethernet interfaces don't report one for historical reasons).

Running cat /sys/class/net/enp6s0/type returns 1, and if The meaning of the /sys/class/net//type value is to be believed then it is reporting an ethernet type.

That reports the link type, not the interface type – e.g. it also reports 1 for VLAN interfaces or bridges because they also emulate an Ethernet link – but there is a different DEVTYPE field (seen in the sysfs uevent file, and from there available through libudev) that says "DEVTYPE=vlan" or "DEVTYPE=bridge" for those devices, while no devtype is reported for real Ethernet interfaces. So a networkd Type=vlan would compare DEVTYPE against the string "vlan", while Type=ether would expect it to be absent instead of DEVTYPE=ether.
